Question about polynomial that gives exact value of $\sin{10^{\circ}}$
When trying to determine the exact value of $\sin{10^{\circ}}$, I proceeded as follows:
$\sin{30^{\circ}}=\frac{1}{2}$.
Then using $\sin{3\theta}=3\sin{\theta}-4\sin^{3}{\theta}$ I can write $\frac{1}{2}=3\sin{10^{\circ}}-4\sin^{3}{10^{\circ}}$
Letting $x=\sin{10^{\circ}}$ the value of $\sin{10^{\circ}}$ presumably (this is the bit I'm not sure about) becomes a real solution to the cubic equation $8x^3-6x+1=0$.
Now, this equation has solutions $x=-0.94, x=0.17, x=0.77$.
I know only one of these can be the exact value of $\sin{10^{\circ}}$, so:
1: Is there a way to know which of these is the actual value (yes, I know geometrically it much be the middle answer, but is there a better explanation than this?)
2: I assume that the other two solutions come about because of the cube roots of unity, but again, is there a better explanation?

If the only fact we're using about $\sin 10^\circ$ is that it's a root of $6x^3-6x+1$, then (tautologically) we won't be able to distinguish it from the other roots of $6x^3-6x+1$. So we definitely need to input some other fact about $\sin 10^\circ$ to identify that specific root.

First, you made a typo as your $\frac{1}{2}=3\sin 10^{\circ}-\color{red}{3}\sin^3 10^{\circ}$ should be $\frac{1}{2}=3\sin 10^{\circ}-\color{red}{4}\sin^3 10^{\circ}$ instead (note this comes from your earlier correct $\sin{3\theta}=3\sin{\theta}-4\sin^{3}{\theta}$ identity). As such, your cubic equation should instead be $\color{red}{8}x^3-6x+1=0$. Second, re: the larger positive value (which should be about $0.7660$ instead), consider what happens when you use $\theta=50^{\circ}$ instead of $\theta=10^{\circ}$.

None of those solutions looks right. The corrrect answer is $0.173.....$ It seems like you should also get $\sin 50^\circ,$ since $\sin 150^\circ = \sin 30^\circ,$ and $\sin -70^\circ$

Thanks everyone for picking up the error with the 6 that should have been an 8. Big mistake, now fixed.

I'm afraid you've made an error, since the minimal polynomial of $\sin 10^\circ$ is actually $$8x^3 - 6x + 1.$$
To see why, let $\theta = \pi/18 = 10^\circ$ so that
$$\sin 3\theta = \sin \frac{\pi}{6} = \frac{1}{2}.$$
Then the triple angle identity is
$$\begin{align}
\sin 3\theta &= \sin \theta \cos 2\theta + \sin 2\theta \cos \theta \\
&= \sin \theta (1 - 2\sin^2 \theta) + 2 \sin \theta \cos^2 \theta \\
&= \sin \theta - 2\sin^3 \theta + 2 \sin \theta (1 - \sin^2 \theta) \\
&= \sin \theta - 2\sin^3 \theta + 2 \sin \theta - 2 \sin^2 \theta \\
&= 3 \sin \theta - \color{red}{4} \sin^3 \theta.
\end{align}$$
You wrote this identity correctly but then changed $4$ to $3$ in the next step.  Instead, it should be
$$\frac{1}{2} = 3 \sin \theta - 4 \sin^3 \theta \implies 1 = 6 \sin \theta - 8 \sin^3 \theta.$$
The resulting roots are numerically
$$x \in \{-0.939693, 0.173648, 0.766044\}.$$  This makes more sense since we require $|\sin \theta| \le 1$, so if a root is real, it should not have absolute value exceeding $1$.
That said, how do we know which root is which?  The negative root is obviously not $\sin 10^\circ$.  The other root, $0.766044$, is also not desired because $\sin 10^\circ < \sin 30^\circ = \frac{1}{2}$.  So that's how I would reason in this case, although more generally, it may become difficult to tell which root is which.
What do these other roots mean?  Where did they come from?  Well, when we used the triple angle identity, we need to remember that the periodicity of $f(z) = \sin z$, namely $f(z + 2\pi) = f(z)$, implies that $\theta + \frac{2\pi}{3}$ is also going to satisfy the triple angle identity, since
$$\sin 3(\theta + \tfrac{2\pi}{3}) = \sin (3\theta + 2\pi) = \sin 3\theta.$$
And the same is true of $\theta - \frac{2\pi}{3}$.  So in other words, if $\sin 10^\circ$ is a root of $8x^3 - 6x + 1$, then so are $\sin 130^\circ$ and $\sin -110^\circ = \sin 250^\circ$.  If you calculate their numerical values, you will find
$$\sin 130^\circ \approx 0.766044, \quad \sin 250^\circ \approx -0.939693.$$

Yes, agree on the polynomial error - I just saw it myself - will fix.

So, if I understand correctly, it is the periodicity of the function that creates the extra solutions in the polynomial and not the cube-roots of unity? Makes a lot of sense, now that I think about it, but for some reason it never occurred to me when first trying to find the exact value. So thanks.
